# ¿Puedo ponerle un formato a un valor introducido en una matriz de Strings?

Tags: java, matrices, hashmap

Estoy intentando hacer una clase que, dado un HashMap de Strings y Doubles, me los imprima en formato de tabla usando matrices
[image: La tabla es algo de este estilo]

El problema está en que quiero que los headers (la columna más a la izquierda y la última fila) estén en la misma matriz, o sea, no quiero imprimirlos aparte. Como se puede ver, el número 100 tiene un espacio de más y mueve las barritas que estoy queriendo poner. Esto creo que se solucionaría si lo imprimiera con un `printf` y dándole unos espacios determinados, pero en este caso lo estoy introduciendo en la matriz y no sé si se pueda hacer o si hay alguna otra alternativa.

El código que se encarga de esa parte en específico es

```
    public void drawHeaders() {
    Set<String> listOfKeys = hashMapAux.keySet();
    String[] arrayOfKeys =  listOfKeys.toArray(new String[0]);
    int numbers = 0;
    for(int i = auxMatrix.length - 2, k = auxMatrix.length - 1; i >= 0 || k >= 0; i -= 2, k -= 2) {
        if(k >= 0) {
            auxMatrix[i][0] = "   |";
            auxMatrix[k][0] = String.valueOf(numbers) + " |";
            numbers += 10;
        }   
    }
}
```

No sé si sea adecuado pero me gustaría preguntar acerca de ese método `keySet. Estoy agregando los valores en orden pero al pasarlo al array (la línea de abajo) no me los imprime de esa forma y no sé por qué si, según yo, no los estoy moviendo para nada más. ¿Es normal? ¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo?

```
public static void  main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Double> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    hashMap.put("Primera", 2.0);
    hashMap.put("Segunda", 5.0);
    hashMap.put("Tercera", 10.0);
    hashMap.put("Cuarta", 6.0);
    PrintAsGraphic printAsGraphic = new PrintAsGraphic(hashMap);
    
}
```

Resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Algunas implementaciones de `Map` optimizan la obtención de valores, y para ello puede que alteren el orden de sus elementos; en cambio, otras como `TreeMap` garantizan el orden de sus elementos, pero ordenando consistentemente las claves, por lo regular en orden alfabético.

En tu caso, para preservar el orden de los elementos conforme al orden de inserción puedes usar la clase `LinkedHashMap`.